# Building a docker play application with gradle

Tags: gradle, playframework, docker

I am trying to build a docker container containing a play application using gradle, and I am having problems with the way gradle configures and runs the build. The problem is that in order to 'containerize' the play application that gradle builds using the play plugin, I need to build the docker container (using the *com.palantir.docker:0.5.2* plugin) from a folder that is created as a result of the execution of the *playBinary* task.

I tried to copy the folders that the mentioned task creates by adding a new task like this:

```
task copyDockerDependencies(type: Copy, dependsOn: build){
    from 'build/stage/playBinary'
    into 'build/docker'
}
```

But when I execute the `gradle clean playBinary docker` task it fails because:

`Skipping task ':copyDockerDependencies' as it has no source files.`

I know this is due to the fact that the folder build doesn't exists at the time the project is configured, so I was wondering is there a way to perform this check at execution time so that folder and those files exists, and the `docker build` task is able to find them?

I tried to use `doLast` inside my copy task but that doesn't work either. Any help will be appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is interested, I manage to do it using an Execution task like this:

```
task copyDockerFiles(type: Exec){
    workingDir '.'
    commandLine '/bin/cp', '-r', "${origin}", "${destination}"
}
```

Although I don't particularly like the idea of adding bash scripting to the gradle build. I don't know it this is the right approach to achieve this, but it works. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The palantir docker gradle plugin copies task outputs from any tasks you depend on. So depending on the 'dist' task will copy the output (including the play binary) to the docker build context.

See: https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker/issues/42